# Jquery hover action diappears when going to next div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im new to learning JQuery. Im doing a sample from JQuery Novice to Ninja and Im getting an error when I move my mouse over then next item. The #navigation_blob dissapears it could be a css problem for all I know but run the code tell me what you think I need to do. Im using the easing plugin

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('<div id="navigation_blob"></div>').css({
            width: $('#navigation li:first a').width() + 10,
            height: $('#navigation li:first a').height() + 10
        }).appendTo('#navigation');

        $('#navigation a').hover(function () {
            $('#navigation_blob').animate(
                { width: $(this).width() + 10, left: $(this).position().left },
                { duration: 'slow', easing: 'easeOutElastic', queue: false }
            )
        }, function () {
            $('#navigation_blob')
                .stop(true)
                .animate(
                    {width: 'hide'},
                    {duration: 'slow', easing: 'easeOutCirc', queue: false}
                )
                .animate({
                    left: $('#navigation li:first a').position().left }, 'fast'
                );                   
        });
    });


<style type="text/css">
   #navigation li
   {
       display:inline-block
   }
   #navigation_blob 
   {
       background-color:Blue; position:absolute; float:left
   }       
</style>
<ul id="navigation"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">About Us</a></li><li><a href="#">Buy!</a></li><li><a href="#">Gift Ideas</a></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the `width: 'hide'` in the first `.animate()` of the second `.hover()` function:

```
//...
}, function () {
    $('#navigation_blob')
        .stop(true)
        .animate(
            {width: 'hide'},
//...
```

I think your blob will, essentially, have `display: none;` once that animation completes so further manipulations of its width or position will have no visible effect. If you say `{width: 0}` it should work okay: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/YaVzd/

You can also try adding an explicit `.show()` before the hover-in animation but that produces some odd effects: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/uH9yJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the version of jQuery is the culprit here.  In **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/8SNsy/)** everything looks fine (using jQuery 1.4.2).  However, if you change the version to 1.4.4 (the latest version), things start acting weird.  Additionally, I downloaded the code from this book and it looks like the version of jQuery that this sample is using 1.4.

This makes sense if the author's update log is correct.  According to the [plugin's website](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/), the last update was 12/11/07, which may mean development has stopped, but at the very least it probably means the plugin is out of date.

Hope that helps.